# PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-play-console, google-play-games

i am trying to fetch my game stats (through API) which is on playstore. but i can't.
It give me above error. but, i give full permissions to this user.

i have installed [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client) gem. and follow it's documentation.